# What is the C#/.NET 4.0+ way to implement a cancellable background thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

Before .NET 4.0, my understanding is that if one wanted to start a thread to do some work which could be cancelled, one would start a `BackgroundWorker`. .NET 4 brought about the TAP model, and a whole bunch of new async and threading stuff. Is the `BackgroundWorker` still the way to do it?

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` is *one* way to do work in the background; it's certainly not the only way.  The same is true of the TPL; it's *a* way to do a lot of things (including to start cancellable work in a background thread), it's not the *only* way of doing pretty much any of those things.  If they're useful to you, great, use them, if not, go ahead and use other tools to solve your problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `async` (and the corollary keyword `await`) are both .NET 4.5, and not available in 4.0. If you want to use `Task`s at all, I highly recommend upgrading to .NET 4.5. Even in 4.0, however, there areseveral overloaded methods which optionally take [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx)s that can be used to cancel running work.

**EDIT:** As pointed out in comments, there [are ways](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx) to get `async`/`await` on .NET 4.0 - you just need less work and have more library support in 4.5. Not something I would recommend without a dire need for XP support.

As of .NET 4.5, the [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class is not marked as [`[Obsolete]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so there's no reason you shouldn't continue using it directly.

[The `Thread` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) contains a direct `.Abort()` method, which can be used to create a worker which can be cancelled. Note that this abort happens via throwing a `ThreadAbortException` in the running thread, thus allowing a `catch` statement to still perform any cleanup in the event of thread abortion.

Comment: Hey, thanks for clearing up the 4.0 vs 4.5 difference with `Task` and `async`/`await`! I am indeed using 4.5-- I upgraded my project from 3.5.

Comment: Technically, you *can* use `async` / `await` in a 4.0 project, so long as you're using VS2013 or higher and have added [the async targeting pack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx) NuGet package. However, you do need to install some 4.0 hotfixes, so unless you need XP support, 4.5 is a better option.

Answer (score 5):

In modern code, I'd recommend using `Task.Run` with a `CancellationToken`. The `BackgroundWorker` style of cancellation is rather convoluted in comparison: it requires the `DoWork` delegate to monitor its own `BackgroundWorker` instance, and treats a cancellation request as a boolean rather than an exception.

I have a [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-4.html) that goes into more detail.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going for this approach -- after reading an article you wrote on MSDN!